# Android - Multiple Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I have written an application that has 11 different relative layouts, all declared in the same file, but only one is showing, the other are hidden. Then I implemented a drawer that allows me to choose which layout showing.
The problem is that these layouts are quite heavy (about 3000 lines), so my app runs slow, especially when starting another activity or when using searchview.

How can I avoid this? (I have tried to split the layouts but in this way I can only load one of them one time in the activty and I want to switch between them using the drawer)

Comment: Please have a look at fragments. This is exactly what they are intended for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one solution for your issue - **start using fragments**. Why? Please read carefully texts below:

#### From: Android Developers Guide - [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

> Android introduced fragments in Android 3.0 (API level 11), primarily
> to support more dynamic and flexible UI designs on large screens, such
> as tablets. Because a tablet's screen is much larger than that of a
> handset, there's more room to combine and interchange UI components.
> Fragments allow such designs without the need for you to manage
> complex changes to the view hierarchy. By dividing the layout of an
> activity into fragments, you become able to modify the activity's
> appearance at runtime and preserve those changes in a back stack
> that's managed by the activity.

#### From: Android Developers Training - [Building a Flexible UI](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

> When designing your application to support a wide range of screen
> sizes, you can reuse your fragments in different layout configurations
> to optimize the user experience based on the available screen space.
>
> (...)
> The `FragmentManager` class provides methods that allow you to add,
> remove, and replace fragments to an activity at runtime in order to
> create a dynamic experience.

You can also read these StackOverFlow posts:

- [Why use Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827072/why-use-fragments)
- [What is the benefit of using Fragments in Android, rather than Views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617696/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-fragments-in-android-rather-than-views)

Check also this site to get some great tutorials: [[CodePath] Fragments](https://guides.codepath.com/android#fragments)

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Use `<FrameLayout>` Tag in your xml and inflate them with different Fragments as required

Take a look at the related documentation. This is exactly what you need: [Fragmenting](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)